# Help Find Unknown Bad Zener: Digital Volt Amp Meter

Tags: amplifier, digital-logic, zener, display, meter

This is Digital Volt Amp meter display module. Working voltage was max 30v and I burned the transistor BL P11 NPN (1A) with more input. Replaced with CXT5551 (600mA), operating current for module is about 20mA so this should work.

But display didn't turned on and found Zener to be bad when tested after removing. Tested with multimeter on diode mode beep both side. Resistance is 2 ohms both direction. Nothing written on the Zener. I am not expert in electronics so need your help in finding this.

[74HC138D Datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT138.pdf)

Thanks a lot!

[image: Volt Amp Meter Back]

Comment: Such a repair session after an overvoltage breakdown easily ends in replacing all ICs. Verify the CXT5551 pinout, it is mirrored, pin is emitter, which does not match the layout. First try 3.9 V zener, then 5.6 V.

Comment: Transistor pinout is correct. Tried 3.9v and 5.1v zener. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Working voltage was max 30v and I burned the transistor BL P11 NPN (1A) with more input.

BL P11 is the marking of BCX56 which is a 80V/1A NPN transistor.

The 10k (if I read it correctly) resistor, burnt transistor and the Zener appear to be forming a series pass linear regulator to have an output of one diode drop less than the Zener voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fztmCr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I can't see properly but I assume that the regulator is there to power the logic ICs which normally should be supplied with a voltage of maximum 6V. So first, I'd expect the Zener to be something like a 5V6 or 3V9 to have 3.3V or 5V logic supply.

The voltage across the transistor will be the input-output difference. To burn the transistor this difference should exceed 80V. So you must have applied ~100V. Note that, in this case, quite possibly the BJT's junctions would be shorted together so the ICs supplied from this regulator could have been exposed to your high input voltage. This may result in shorted supply rails inside the ICs. And that is probably why you see a short across the Zener because after the BJTs death and the ICs the Zener will effectively be in parallel with the supply rails of the ICs.

So the ICs and transistor might be showing a short, not the Zener (although the Zener could have died as well because of a high voltage and therefore high bias current). I'd worry more about the ICs rather than the Zener here.

Comment: The power supply I used is maxed out at 32VDC. That's where it burned. The zener showed shorted outside the pcb not inside. Tested 3.9v and 5.1v zener and it didn't turned on. I don't see its worth trying new IC here. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Paul `The zener showed shorted outside the pcb not inside.` do you measure short across the ICs' supply pins on the PCB now?

Comment: VCC and GND of IC is sorted. Do you suggest replacing it?

Comment: There are few variants if you look here http://surl.li/rbygo
But it cost about 40-45% of new module. Since zener is unknown. Also if you look at first pin of transistor the board burned including wire trace for that pin. I added a small wire with resistor assuming it was connected there.

Is this chip needs to be programmed? I'd regret if it didn't work. 

Thanks a lot for you help. Thank you, Thank you.

Comment: @Paul it's unclear if only one IC is supplied from the same rails. Usually, having a fault on supply rails such as overvoltage results in an almost total destruction. Even if some ICs don't show any short they still might have damaged partially which causes a malfunction in the entire product.